# Sort files in directory using extended file attributes

Tags: bash, unix, file-attributes

I have a number of files in a directory, and I add extended file attributes to them

```
setfattr -n user.processorder -v 2 myfile.txt
```

I was wondering, is it possible to iterate over the files in the directory with a FOR loop but sorting them according to the extended file attribute "processorder"?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think `for` and the shell has a shortcut for ordering by an arbitrary defined extended attribute. You'll probably need to write a script that calls `getfattr` to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to do that on an XFS filesystem

Adding attributes

`attr -s some.attr -V 1 file3
attr -s some.attr -V 2 file1
attr -s some.attr -V 3 file2`

Reading and sorting on them

`ls -1 file* | xargs -I '{}' bash -c "attr -g some.attr '{}' | tr '\n' ' ' ; echo" | sort -n -t ':' -k2,2
Attribute "some.attr" had a 1 byte value for file3: 1 
Attribute "some.attr" had a 1 byte value for file1: 2 
Attribute "some.attr" had a 1 byte value for file2: 3`

Comment: By doing a little edit on your code i managed to print the filenames sorted by the extended attribute, like this:     ls -1 | xargs -I '{}' bash -c "attr -g some.ordemprocessamento '{}' | tr '\n' ' ' ; echo" | sort -n -t ':' -k1,1 | awk '{print $9;}' | while read x; do echo "${x//:}"; done

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify your OS, but it might go like this on **macOS**

```
# write 2 as attribute "v" on file "a"
xattr -w v 2 a
xattr -w v 3 b
xattr -w v 1 c

# read attribute "v" of file "a"
xattr -p v a
2

# sort files by attribute "v"
xattr -p v a b c | sort -t: -k2 -n
c: 1
a: 2
b: 3
```